# Problem using Spring Cloud Vault with @DynamicPropertySource

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-vault-config, testcontainers-junit5

When using `TestContainers` to start a `Vault` container, the port that is exposed by the container is randomly selected during startup.

```
@Container
static VaultContainer vaultContainer = new VaultContainer<>("vault:1.7.2")
  .withVaultToken(TOKEN)
  .withInitCommand("secrets enable --path foo kv-v2")
  .withInitCommand("kv put foo/app bar=foo");
```

Using a `@DynamicPropertySource` to override properties

```
@DynamicPropertySource
static void addProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
   registry.add("spring.cloud.vault.host",()->vaultContainer.getHost());
   registry.add("spring.cloud.vault.port",()->vaultContainer.getFirstMappedPort());
   registry.add("spring.cloud.vault.uri",()->"http://"+vaultContainer.getHost()+":"+vaultContainer.getFirstMappedPort());
   registry.add("spring.cloud.vault.token",()->TOKEN);
}
```

does not work since `Spring Cloud Vault` does not seem to "see" the added properties.

The issue is present in `Spring-Boot 2.5.1` and `Spring-Cloud-Vault-Config 3.0.3`.

A small project showing the issue can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/tzie0062/issue-testcontainers-spring-cloud-vault).

Am I doing something wrong or is there an alternative way to override the configuration?

When using `Spring-Vault` with a `@VaultPropertySource` instead of `Spring-Cloud-Vault` things work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

According to:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/602#event-4926845049
it's a `spring-framework` issue.